# Error installing CocoaPods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am trying to install the latest CocoaPods (which is 0.36.1) but it shows me the following error.

```
$ gem install cocoapods
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'xcodeproj' (~> 0.23.1) in any repository
```

### Sudo?

Btw, in the answered questions some are proposed using `sudo get install cocoapods`. You do need `sudo` indeed if you are using the system-wide ruby executable. I am using `rbenv` for my ruby management, it is installed locally for the user and does not need `sudo`.

### Update

The `gem install cocoapods` command worked the following day. Mystery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you could try an older version of the pods.

I tried: `sudo gem install cocoapods -v 0.34.0` and this worked for me.

Comment: I need 0.36.1 unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

For your error you should do like this

`i) $ sudo gem install xcodeproj`

`ii) $ sudo gem install cocoapods`

for pod version you can verify `pod --version`

Comment: Does not help. `gem install xcodeproj` installs xcodeproj-0.22.0. But latest cocoa pods 0.36.1 requires version 0.23.1.

Comment: Fetching and installing `xcodeproj` will not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to update your gems repo.

try issuing "gem update" in a terminal. Can't remenber if you need sudo.

Try that, and then try installing xcodeproj and cocoapods again.

Regards
Steffen

Comment: Issuing `gem update` will only update gems that are already _installed_.

Answer (score 0):

If the automatic downloading of xcodeproj 0.23 fails, you can fetch the gem file manually:

```
gem fetch xcodeproj -v 0.23.0
```

This will put the .gem file in your current directory.

Then you can install the gem:

```
gem install xcodeproj -v 0.23.0
```

If the xcodeproj gem installs successfully, you can continue with your install of cocoapods as usual:

```
gem install cocoapods
```

Comment: Fetching and installing `xcodeproj` will not help at all.

Answer (score 0):

Next time that occurs, run the command `gem sources -u` to update your source cache and try again.

Comment: did not work. "source cache successfully updated"
and still getting the same error as posted in question.